# Relative import works on CLI but not in script

Tags: python, import

I addded the project root of my python project to the `PYTHONPATH`. Now the import of my modules works in the `CLI` of python bot NOT in a python script.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same python interpreter in cli and with the script ?

Comment: Yes, printing `sys.path` in my scripts returns that my project is included in `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your script with -v option.

> python -v yourscript.py

This will trace all the import statements and look or do grep for your project name. If it's not in that, then either it's not at all added to your python path or you're running different python interpreter.

Comment: I found out that works directly in my windows shell. I'm using `eclipse` with `pydev`. It seems that only eclipse doesn't find the right directory. Is there any additional configuration needed?

Comment: There might be a cache problem with `pydev`. Remove and add the python interpreter again and try restarting the `eclipse`.